# Kendo UI Timezone displays date one day behind

Tags: jquery, datetime

I'm working with Kendo UI, hating it more every second, and I think I've found a fix for my problem but I'm stuck in the last stretch.  So our servers are on PST and for whatever reason, our Kendo UI grid displays the date one day behind of what the actual value is.

They have a 'fix' on their site but it doesn't exactly slide in.  Here's what I've managed to cull together:

Here's the column code:

```
columns.Bound(e => e.eventDate).Width(120).Title("Event Date").ClientTemplate("#= parseDateGrid(eventDate) #").EditorTemplateName("Date");
```

and the code to parse the date:

```
var offsetMiliseconds = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;

function parseDateGrid(e) {
    var eventDate = null;
    if (e.sender) 
        eventDate = e.sender._value;
    else
        eventDate = e;
```

//eventDate = Fri Mar 19 2055 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

```
    var sDate = eventDate.toString();

    sDate = sDate.replace(/\d+/,
     function (n) { return parseInt(n) + offsetMiliseconds });
```

//sDate = "Fri Mar 14400019 2055 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)"

```
    var eventDateFormatted = new Date(sDate);

    return eventDateFormatted;
}
```

The UI returns 'Invalid Date' where the eventDate field is supposed to be.  I think the problem is that I'm incorrectly formatting the string back to a date after the replace function.  Feel like I'm close here, thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT:

using this function:

```
    function addOffset(events) {
    for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
        var eventDate1 = new Date(events[i].eventDate); // for testing purpose

        var sdate = eventDate1.getTime() + offsetMiliseconds;
        var eventDateFormatted = new Date(sdate);

        return eventDateFormatted.toLocaleDateString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need the replace function

use **getTime()** and add your milliseconds to it

```
var offsetMiliseconds = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
var eventDate = new Date("Fri Mar 19 2055 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)"); // for testing purpose

var sdate =  eventDate.getTime() + offsetMiliseconds;
var eventDateFormatted = new Date(sdate);
alert(eventDateFormatted);
```

here is a jsfiddle for you with intermediate alerts

https://jsfiddle.net/u3h0bjyp/

Comment: Thanks for the comment, think I'm close although I'm not sure how to get the date into your routine.  Updated the question.

Comment: what is the value of e that you get in parseDateGrid function?

Comment: "/Date(2689041600000)/"

Comment: you should use this logic in your parseDateGrid function, as it is called for each row

Comment: Thanks Karthik, this got me where I needed.